# Refresh Grid when not using a data provider?

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow, vaadin-grid

I have a Vaadin Grid that I am filling manually using setItems().  When I click on one of the items, I feed it to a FormLayout that is inside a Dialog for editing.  I pass a reference to my Service class into the Dialog to save the Item when the edit is complete.

When the Dialog is closed, I want it to fire an event that will cause the grid to be refreshed, via a method in the grid's view class.  When I have done this with Spring events, even passing the grid object, itself, as a reference into the Dialog and then back into the event, a different instance of the grid is being updated.  I assume this is from the "every browser tab is its own view instance" concept of Vaadin.

So!  How do I accomplish this?  How do I get an event or a message from the dialog to cause the original grid to be refreshed?

Code structure for reference:

```
View
  Grid

Dialog
  Form
Selecting entry in the grid triggers a new Dialog(new Form(event.getItem)), then a dialog.open();
```

Comment: Can you provide example code? It's hard to give an answer that will work from the explanation.

Comment: Pass in a callback, that refreshes the grid to the code opening the
dialog.  Then call that if in an appropriate time (e.g. when saving the
form is successful)